# ibm watson text to speech api create pause

Tags: ibm-watson

I am using ibm watson's text-to-speech api, how do you generate a slight longer pause via the text? I would like to insert pause or silence into the text so when watson convert the text to speech there is a noticeable pause or 1 or 2 seconds?

Comment: sorry i figure this out using the break tag <breadk></break>

Answer (score 3):

sorry i figure this out using the break tag  which is listed here https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/SSML.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Search for (Speech Synthesis Markup Language)SSML tags, when using ibm watson's text-to-speech api.

example: `<break time="3s">`

This will add a pause of 3 sec.